# Symfony3 form login only works on "main" firewall

Tags: php, forms, authentication, symfony

I'm trying to build a custom firewall for my Symfony3 website. I've been following the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html), and was able to get it to work for the `main` firewall. My desired functionality is the ability for a user to login with their username and password, using Symfony's native classes. Here is my `SecurityController`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/m/login", name="model_login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get("security.authentication_utils");
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Model/login.html.twig', [
            "error"     => $error,
            "lastUsername"  => $lastUsername
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is **exactly** the same as the sample code, except with the routing settings changed. My login form renders fine. I get no errors when I submit the form, and I have my form POSTing to this exact controller. My view works perfectly as I am able to authenticate when my security settings are under "main." Here is my `security.yml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        doctrine_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Model
                property: username

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Model:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~

        model_area:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: doctrine_provider
            pattern: ^/m/
            form_login:
                login_path: model_login
                check_path: model_login
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/m/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/m/, roles: ROLE_MODEL }
```

My providers and encoders function properly, as exemplified by my success when authenticating under the "main" firewall. However, when I attempt to put my settings under "model_area," submitting my form just redirects me to the login form, with no authentication. I only added the `pattern: ^/m/` and `- { path: ^/m/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` so I do not block access to my login form. Everything else remained the same (even the route names!).

I have a route `/m/model_dashboard`, which throws an error, saying "*full authentication is required to access this resource.*" So clearly my access control settings are working properly, however, it is not redirecting to my login form when I attempt to access a protected resource.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm extremely confused as to why the authentication would work under `main` but not under my custom firewall, which had the same exact settings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was my `main` firewall. I did not know that firewalls are determined similarly to routes, top to bottom. Every request was being filed under the "main" firewall (which has no form_login), which was why my login code wasn't working. I removed the `main` firewall and it is working beautifully. Here is what my updated `security.yml` looks like now:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        doctrine_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Model
                property: username

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Model:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        model_area:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: doctrine_provider
            pattern: ^/m/
            form_login:
                login_path: model_login
                check_path: model_login
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/m/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/m/, roles: ROLE_MODEL }
```